# Format equation and text with latex

Tags: latex

I am using latex to do a report, I have problem with this lines:

```
\[A_{1},A_{2},A_{3},...,A_{M}\] \text{are a the set of alternatives.
Alternatives represent the different choices of action available to
the decision maker. Usually, the set of alternatives is assumed to be
finite, ranging from several to hundreds. They are supposed to be
screened, prioritized and eventually ranked}
```

The result is shown in this figure:
[image]

and I want it to be like this:

"A1,A2,A3,...,An are a the set of alternatives.Alternatives represent the different choices of action available to the decision maker. Usually, the set of alternatives is assumed to be finite, ranging from several to hundreds. They are supposed to be screened, prioritized and eventually ranked."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace:

```
\[ A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}, ..., A_{M} \]
```

by:

```
\( A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}, ..., A_{M} \)
```

You also might want to take a look at [LaTeX mathematics environments](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Mathematics_environments).

I hope this will help you.

[Edit]

If you compile this file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\(A_{1},A_{2},A_{3},...,A_{M}\) are a the set of alternatives.
Alternatives represent the different choices of action available to
the decision maker. Usually, the set of alternatives is assumed to be
finite, ranging from several to hundreds. They are supposed to be
screened, prioritized and eventually ranked
\end{document}
```

You will get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response but it won't work , now it gives me ethis error: Undefined control sequence

Comment: Oh! Remove `\text`, it will work. `\text` is provided by the `amsmath` package and should be used inside mathematics environments.

Comment: same error even if i remove all of the sentence

Comment: Have you any additional information about the error ? What is written just below `! Undefined control sequence.` ?

Comment: Undefined control sequence 1.140 centerin and tha 1.140 line contains this  }%

Comment: also Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph

Comment: Just to be sure. Have you removed the bracket (i.e. `}`) associate with `\text` ?

Comment: It should work properly. According to the error message, the problem is around line 140 in your file. Does it link to the lines you have cited in the question ?

Comment: No it does not link the line i cited are in chapter.tex and i compile from another .xtex  which is  like main errors are in the main

Comment: Hard for me to see what is going on. Have you managed to compile the main when `\[ \]` and `\text` were used?

Comment: Now no , it does not work at all. thank you for all your provided answers  i am going to check my main probably  something wrong happened

Comment: now , it works very well as your example , just the reason that there is a line with \centerin i replace it by \center

Comment: Great! By the way, since you're new to StackOverflow, don't forget to click to accept the answer.